# Infinitely loop video on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

So, my plan is to have a video, after clicking play, infinitely loop on a mobile html site. [JSfiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/wayrguxr/1/). As mobile html5 is buggy and does not work properly I tried to make a function via javascript to replay the video each time it ends or pauses, however, this isn't working.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank You

```
    <script>
document.getElementById("database").addEventListener("ended", myFunction, false);
document.getElementById("database").addEventListener("pause", myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("database").play();
    if (document.getElementById("database").pause()) {
        document.getElementById("database").play();
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("database").ended()) {
        document.getElementById("database").play();
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: console? How do I bring up a console?

Comment: [How to open the javascript console in different browsers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)